# Why are dolphins born tail first?

Tags: evolution, zoology, reproduction, marine-biology

I heard most dolphins are born tail first. I have read many explanations from books and internet articles and they said that dolphins are born tail first to prevent them from drowning.

But now I don't get this explanation. There must be no air in the mother's womb, so the baby dolphin can't breathe either way. I think they get oxygen from the umbilical cord until it's disconnected.

If this is true, why would they drown if they are born head first? Why are dolphins born tail first unlike most mammals?

Comment: Searching on youtube you find videos of head-first births of whales. So, even though tail-first seems to be more common, head-first does work. Since tail-first is otherwise uncommon in mammals, there is probably an evolutionary advantage to it. Maybe drowning becomes a problem in the head-first situation if the process is taking too long.

Answer (score 2):

Cetaceans are born tail first for two reasons:

1. Avoid drowning
2. Being in the same direction of the mother.

As you already wrote, they developed this particular way of giving birth to avoid drowning of the calve. As they are mammals like us, they need to breathe immediately after the birth (think about us: we come out in a world of air and we are forced to breathe immediately). So, many complications can occur while giving birth and it may take long time. If calves go out by head first, they can drown easily. On the other hand, as soon as they are totally out, they swim and are forced to go to the surface by the mother in order to have their first breath.

The second reason is that, in this way, they are already in the same direction of the mother, so they can easily swim and recognise her. Imagine being born in a dark pool, where you can't see nothing. A bit confusing right? But they just come out and see the mother, that can guide them easily where to swim, instead of turning back, spend energy and precious time. They have to be quick, because they need to breathe and also need to swim away! A calf is an easy prey!

This adaption came with the evolution of the cetaceans. In fact, some of the ancestors were supposed to give birth head-first just as land mammals. But, as other adaptations to the environment, also this trait was found to be evolutionary successful. Also other mammals were found to give birth in this way (e.g. Manatees and reported cases for pinnipeds. For more references see: *Gol’din, P. E. (2011). Case of Cephalic Presentation of a Foetus in a Harbour Porpoise Phocoena phocoena (Cetacea, Phocoenidae), with Notes on Other Aquatic Mammals. Вестник зоологии, (45,№ 5), 473-477. DOI:10.2478/v10058-011-0030-5*).

You can find the info I shared here with references: *North American Nature (2020). Why Are Whales Mammals?* [https://northamericannature.com/why-are-whales-mammals/][1]

Comment: Thanks!! I have read in a book that Manatees give birth head or tail first in about fifty-fifty. And hippo, giving birth in the water, seems mostly head-first. I think the head-first would more efficiently resolve breathe issue when they faced problems at umbilical cord during the birth because mothers could lie with her belly up at the surface. But the tail-first has no chance. So I doubted it might not be the breathe problem. The direction problem gave me insight. Now I got interested in birth of Dugongs. They lives far out at ocean, where the direction might be more important in birth.

Comment: Of course, cetaceans are really different, as they usually live out in the ocean, so harder in any case than being around the coast:) We also have to consider that we still have a lack of knowledge regarding cetaceans, as they are quite hard to study. But, from what I know and I found, experts agree with those two reasons. Always good to have some discussion too:) And nice to see some interest in a "wired" creature like Dugong!